# Store Flash Player privacy settings in Flash cookies

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-player-11

Can I store Flash Player's privacy settings in Flash cookies using Actionscript 3? I don't know the proper way to develop the Flash cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Flash cookies are used through SharedObject. Flash has its own way of storing its privacy settings through the popup, when camera or microphone is to be published. If you are refering to your own internal privacy protocol, research about SharedObjects. Its quite easy.

Don't forget to flush() :D

Comment: no i m refering to flash privacy settings to be stored in flash cookies is it possible?

Comment: @user2469736 I still don't understand what you want. You can copy some of them from the popup, and store them using SharedObject, and you can read them, but you can't set them, because it requires user interaction, as a security obligation from Adobe. Does that satisfy your question?